# django: how to include inline formset for a foreign key in a model form with crispy form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

For example, I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    login_date =  models.DateField(null=True)
    login_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    notes= models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)

class Sample(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 200)    

class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    login_date=forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(attrs={'id':"login_sample"}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3), initial=datetime.date.today)
    in_notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            'description',
            'login_date',
            'login_by',
            'in_notes',
            ButtonHolder(
                HTML("<button type='submit' class='save btn btn-default' name = 'projectform'>Save</button>"),
            ), 
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['description', 'login_date','login_by',
        'in_shipping_method_tracking_number','in_notes']

class SampleDetailForm(ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            'serial_number',
            'location',
            ButtonHolder(
                HTML("<button type='submit' class='save btn btn-default' name = 'sampleform'>Save</button>"),
            ),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ['octa_number', 'serial_number', 'pctest_number', 'location',]
```

This is how currently I set up models and forms.

I am wondering how could I make a ProjectForm that not only have field of its own, but also a inline formset of SampleForm, where multiple samples could be added/deleted within the model form, just like what we have in admin site. I also would be grateful to know how should I handle the saving in view, and rendering in template.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this, https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/examples/

Here you find examples of model relationship API usage:

**Many-to-many relationships**

**Many-to-one relationships**

**One-to-one relationships**

Comment: ummm thanks but I know how to define those relationship. Instead, I am wondering about implementing inline formset.